# Android expandablelistview with pinned headers

Tags: android, scroll, expandablelistview, instagram, sticky

I'm tying to accomplish an instagram style scrolling view, only with the actual view being an expandablelistview, i've looked around and couldn't find any examples or hints for implementation other then listview being the view at hand.

any thought or has anyone tried it ?
it comes built in in iOS and i'll be really happy implementing it on an expandableListview

thanks

Answer (score 3):

I've recently developed an open source library that provides pinned headers for the `ExpandableListView`. You can take a look at https://github.com/diegocarloslima/FloatingGroupExpandableListView.

Comment: Cudos :) I ended up using DSLV for the dragging cpabilities

Comment: hi diego can u please help me with how to get pinned headers for all the headers and not only the header with currently visible child items I have posted the question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683445/accordion-with-expandable-listview-in-android

Answer (score 1):

- use 3d party library [PinnedHeaderListView](https://github.com/JimiSmith/PinnedHeaderListView)